# Can compiler optimization elminate a function repeatedly called in a for-loop's conditional?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I was reading about hash functions (i'm an intermediate CS student) and came across this:

```
int hash (const string & key, int tableSize) {
    int hasVal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
        hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key[i];

    .....
    return hashVal;
}
```

I was looking at this code and noticed that it would be faster if in the for-loop instead of calling key.length() each time we instead did this:

```
int n = key.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

My question is, since this is such an obvious way to slightly improve performance does the compiler automatically do this for us? I don't yet know much about compilers but I was curious as to the answer of this question. When writing code to use less operations people have often pointed out that the things that I do are often already done for me by the compiler so I'm wasting my time but doing things such as inline functions. I care about this because I am programming a game where physics processing needs to be efficient so that things don't feel clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: It can sometimes...

Long answer:

If the compiler can determine that key.length() is a "constant" value based on the loop itself, then it will be able to optimise out the call. This in turn depends on the definition of the class used (in this case `string`, which we can expect is "well written"). It also relies on the compiler understanding that the loop isn't altering the `key` in a way that alters `key.length()`.

Key elements for this to ever work is that the function is `inline` (or is a template function, `inline` is required to allow it to be included multiple times in different compile units - or available within the same source file) and the source code is in a header file included by the compile unit.

And of course, there is no requirement in the C++ standard that the compiler does this. It is perfectly within the standard compliance to call the function every time.

Comment: technically the function does not have to be tagged as inline for it to be inlined, and the linker can cross compilation units to do more optimizations.  But only with the right flags and compiler versions and its still allowed not to.

Comment: A C++ function is not required to be marked `inline` for the compiler to inline it; despite the keyword name, it actually means something different (that multiple definitions are allowed).

Comment: I've clarified the "inline" part.

Comment: the inline keyword or header file usage is not relavent anymore - it might make more sense to just remove that paragragh - it detracts more than it adds

Comment: Vendors may also add attributes which allow the optimization without knowing the code. For example, GCC has function attributes `pure` and `const`.

Answer (score 2):

It's only safe to move `key.length()` out of the loop if it's a pure function -- that is, one that has no side effects. If the compiler can detect that this is so, then I'd say it's likely it would perform the optimisation.

Unfortunately, unlike Fortran, C++ has no standard way to mark something as pure. If the function is `inline` (or inline-able), then the compiler has the definition and can probably work it out for itself, or at least eliminate the function call.

Marking the member function as `const` guarantees that it won't affect the current instance, but there's no reason in principle that `key.length()` couldn't change some global variable, so I doubt this in itself would be sufficient.

(There are various compiler specific ways of declaring a function pure -- like `__attribute__((pure))` in GCC and compatible compilers (Clang, Intel). Perhaps experiment with these and see whether they make any difference?)

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where optimization will kick in.

1. Smarter compilers will introspect short functions to see if they have impact on the `if` clause. Probably most compilers will `inline` the call, making it an equivalent to what you wrote.
2. On cpu level branch prediction would also make it (substantially) faster compared to more "random" `if`. One of the top question on `SO` shows nice hardcore example of this.

EDIT:
I assumed earlier that declaring method `length() const` will be enough. But it is too weak. Method can still throw random stuff out with out changing the state of object. However I am 100% sure, that decent compilers do introspect functions and methods like I described.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very compiler dependent answer. The only way to be certain is to generate the assembler and have a poke at what it creates (I'd recommend learning how to do that with your compiler and trying it anyway, it's very instructive*).

It's not that obvious of an optimization - the compiler can perform that optimization, but only if it is sure that `.length()` won't change - i.e. no other threads have access to the data and it is able to determine that nothing inside the loop will alter `.length()` The latter is easy to check since it is a const string, but the former less so. Having said that, I'd expect the compiler to assume it was const everywhere at moderate levels of optimization.

*pun intentional; sorry.