# How can I replace an OMP BARRIER by a wait function?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, gfortran, barrier

I want to retire the `!$OMP BARRIER` in the following code so I thought to replace it by a `wait` function.

With `!$OMP BARRIER`:

```
 if (num_thread==1) then
          do i_task=first_task,last_task
             tasklist_GRAD(i_task)%state=STATE_READY
             call queue_enqueue_data(master_queue,tasklist_GRAD(i_task))   !< add the list elements to the queue (full queue)
          end do
 end if

   
 !$OMP BARRIER     ! barrier to retire 

 call master_worker_execution(self,var,master_queue,worker_queue,first_task,last_task,nthreads,num_thread,lck)
```

Without `!$OMP BARRIER`:

```
if (num_thread==1) then
          omp_start=omp_get_wtime() !start 
          do i_task=first_task,last_task
             tasklist_GRAD(i_task)%state=STATE_READY
             call queue_enqueue_data(master_queue,tasklist_GRAD(i_task))   !< add the list elements to the queue (full queue)
          end do
          omp_end=omp_get_wtime() !end 
end if


   


if (num_thread .ne. 1) then 
         call wait(int(omp_end-omp_start)*1000)
end if
           
call master_worker_execution(self,var,master_queue,worker_queue,first_task,last_task,nthreads,num_thread,lck)
```

The definition of the `wait` subroutine:

```
 subroutine wait(omp_start,omp_end)
    real(kind=REAL64),intent(in)::omp_start,omp_end
    real(kind=REAL64)::time 
    time=omp_end-omp_start
    call sleep(int(time))
  end subroutine wait
```

The barrier should let the threads (not thread number 1) wait for the thread number 1 to finish queueing the `master_queue`. That's why I thought to replace it by a `wait` function.

When executing, I get a segfault due to thread safety (I guess). I have a doubt on using the `INT` function because I declared `omp_start` and `omp_end` as `real(kind=REAL64)`.

**EDIT:**
I modified the `wait` subroutine according to the answer I got and did the following:

```
subroutine wait(master_queue)
    type(QUEUE_STRUCT),pointer::master_queue !< the master queue of tasks
    do while (.not. queue_full(master_queue))
       call sleep(1)
    end do
  end subroutine wait
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting results as with `OMP_BARRIER`.

```
logical function queue_full( queue )
    type(QUEUE_STRUCT), intent(in)  :: queue

    queue_full = (queue%size == queue%capacity)

  end function queue_full
```

Comment: It would help to know why you don't want to use `OMP_BARRIER`.

Comment: @veryreverie I'm trying to get rid of `OMP_BARRIER` as I'll have to switch from single node to multi-node. `OMP_BARRIER` doesn't work when you have multiple nodes so I'm trying to prepare the code so that it will also work in multi-node. I got rid of `OMP_TASK` by implementing it from scratch but I still have `OMP_BARRIER`s that I have to replace. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Ah, in that case you need to replace `OMP_BARRIER` with its equivalent in whichever multi-node framework (e.g. MPI) you're using.

Comment: @veryreverie Ok thanks ! I had the idea to check if the queue is full and therefore include a `DO WHILE` loop in the `wait` function which is used to call the `sleep` function with a random input until `master_queue` fills. Is this a good idea? Threads (except thread 1) should check if the queue is full at the same time as thread 1 fills the queue.

Comment: It seems you have a new problem for a new question. Anyway, without knowing what `queue_full` is, no one can diagnose.

Comment: @VladimirF `queue_full` is a simple logical function that verifies if a queue is full or not. I edited my answer.

Comment: @VladimirF the point is that instead of using a barrier, the threads wait for the queue to get full (by the thread number 1). At each time, they find it "not full", they sleep 1 second.

Comment: This looks dangerous. I am not sure if the compiler is not allowed to eliminate the call (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948727/can-compiler-optimization-elminate-a-function-repeatedly-called-in-a-for-loops). I would at least add the `asynchronous` attribute.

Comment: @VladimirF After reading your comment, I changed the declaration of `master_queue` to `type(QUEUE_STRUCT),pointer,asynchronous::master_queue` and by running it, it works perfectly. Can you explain briefly what the `asynchronous` attribute does? Thanks !

Comment: It tells that the variable can become modified by other parts of the program in an asynchronous manner - e.g. by other threads. You may also need some atomic or critical directive for the `queue_full = (queue%size == queue%capacity)` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a segfault is that `omp_start` and `omp_end` are set by thread `1` and read by the other threads. As you currently have it, the order in which this happens is undefined, and so they can (and likely will) be read before they are set.

There is a more fundamental problem however. It looks like you just want the other threads to wait for thread `1` to finish, but there is no way to know in advance how long this will take. As such, there is no way to implement such a wait function. This is the whole reason for using barriers in the first place.

Comment: Yes that's right, I just realized that the other threads don't have the values of omp_start and omp_end even if they are declared as shared variables. They have to wait to get those values and that's not my intention at all. Thank you!